# Logstash one-to-many import from MySQL

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash

I try to import job ads form two MySQL tables (job data and locations) but I'm facing a problem when a job ad has multiple locations. I'm using this MySQL query:

```
SELECT id, company, jobtitle, description, priority, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d %T') AS date, sa_locations.location AS location_name, sa_locations.lat AS location_lat, sa_locations.lon AS location_lon FROM sa_data JOIN sa_locations ON sa_data.id = sa_locations.id ORDER BY id
```

Ignoring the location problem everything is ok, and I receive results like this:

```
{
     "_index" : "jk",
     "_type" : "jobposting",
     "_id" : "26362",
     "_score" : 1.0,
     "_source" : {
       "date" : "2017-04-22 00:00:00",
       "location_name" : "Berlin",
       "location_lat" : "52.520007",
       "location_lon" : "13.404954",
       "@timestamp" : "2017-04-24T07:50:31.660Z",
       "@version" : "1",
       "description" : "Some text here",
       "company" : "Test Company",
       "id" : 26362,
       "jobtitle" : "Architect Data Center Network & Security",
       "priority" : 10,
 },  {
     "_index" : "jk",
     "_type" : "jobposting",
     "_id" : "26363",
     "_score" : 1.0,
     "_source" : {
       "date" : "2017-04-22 00:00:00",
       "location_name" : "Hamburg",
       "location_lat" : "53.551085",
       "location_lon" : "9.993682",
       "@timestamp" : "2017-04-24T07:50:31.660Z",
       "@version" : "1",
       "description" : "Some text here",
       "company" : "Test Company",
       "id" : 26363,
       "jobtitle" : "Architect Data Center Network & Security",
       "priority" : 10,
 }
```

What I'm trying to get is something like this:

```
 {
     "_index" : "jk",
     "_type" : "jobposting",
     "_id" : "26362",
     "_score" : 1.0,
     "_source" : {
       "date" : "2017-04-22 00:00:00",
       "locations" : [ {  "name": "Berlin", "lat" : "52.520007", "lon" : "13.04954" }, {  "name": "Hamburg", "lat" : "53.551085", "lon" :
 "9.993682" } ]
       "@timestamp" : "2017-04-24T07:50:31.660Z",
       "@version" : "1",
       "description" : "Some text here",
       "company" : "Test Company",
       "id" : 26362,
       "jobtitle" : "Architect Data Center Network & Security",
       "priority" : 10,
  }
```

So that if I'm going to search for jobs near Berlin or Hamburg by using a geo_distance filter this job should appear. Is there any way to import data in that way with logstash?

My logstash.conf looks like this:

```
input {
jdbc {
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jk"
jdbc_user => "..."
jdbc_password => "..."
jdbc_driver_library => "/etc/logstash/mysql-connector-java-5.1.41/mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar"
jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
statement => "SELECT id, company, jobtitle, description, priority, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d %T') AS date, sa_locations.location AS location_name, sa_locations.lat AS location_lat, sa_locations.lon AS location_lon
FROM sa_data JOIN sa_locations
ON sa_data.id = sa_locations.id
ORDER BY id
}
}

#filter {
# aggregate {
# task_id => "%{id}"
# code => "
# map['location_name'] = event.get('location_name')
# map['location_lat'] = event.get('location_lat')
# map['location_lon'] = event.get('location_lon')
# map['locations'] ||= []
# map['locations'] < event.get('location_name')}
# map['locations'] < event.get('location_lat')}
# map['locations'] < event.get('location_lon')}
# event.cancel()
# "
# push_previous_map_as_event => true
# timeout => 3
# }
#}

output {
elasticsearch {
index => "jk"
document_type => "jobposting"
document_id => "%{id}"
hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
}
}
```

The filter seemed to be a wrong approach.

Comment: DOB - Was you able to get this working in the end? I have a similar issue and can't get it to work :(

Answer (score 2):

You will still want to aggregate if you have multiple locations for a single id, but your current set up wont create an array of hashes per location (one hash for each row in your locations db).

You can do something like this:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    rename => { 'location_name' => '[location][name]' }
    rename => { 'location_lat' => '[location][lat]' }
    rename => { 'location_long' => '[location][long]' }
  }

  aggregate {
    task_id => '%{id}'
    code => "
      map['locations'] ||= []
      map['locations'] << event.get('location')
    "
    push_previous_map_as_event => true
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but got this error message: Exception in thread "[main]>worker2" java.lang.ClassCastException: expecting List or Map, found class org.logstash.bivalues.StringBiValue

Comment: What was your config file?

Comment: The one above but with your filter added, I just changed "))" to ")" and added "map['id'] = event.get('id')", but without success.

Comment: Hm. I'm not able to reproduce that error when i run the configuration. Have you tried running it with Logstash's ` --config.test_and_exit` flag? A similar problem has been reported [here](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/6142). But can't debug without seeing the entire config.